# Python strptime with "+00" timezone offset format?

Tags: python, date, time, timezone

How can I parse a timezone offset with format `+00` ? Python 3 or python 2

```
from datetime import datetime
s = '2019-04-10 21:49:41.607472+00'
# What must I replace <XX> with, to parse +00 as the timezone offset
d = datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f<XX>')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [dateutil's parse](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) for that:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
s = '2019-04-10 21:49:41.607472+00'
parse(s)
```

> datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 10, 21, 49, 41, 607472, tzinfo=tzutc())

Answer (score 3):

`strptime` uses `%z` to specify a UTC offset in the format of `±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]]`. Since minutes are required and your sample input only has hours, you can concatenate `'00'` to the string before parsing:

```
datetime.strptime(s + '00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')
```

Comment: Python 2.7 says `*** ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format`